# Bootstrap dropdown-menu appearing off-screen when list is scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have an un-ordered list <ul> that needs to have a fixed height.

Each item in the list is associated with a Bootstrap dropdown menu
to be opened by a button (**...**) on each <li> item.

The dropdown menu appears correctly for the first few items.

However, as soon as I scroll down the list and click the **...** button,
the dropdown menu would be shown off-screen.

```
<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="my-list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Item 1</span>
            <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a>Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <span>Item 2</span>
            <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" title="More Actions" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a>Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Item 3</span>
            <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" title="More Actions" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a>Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Item 4</span>
            <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" title="More Actions" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a>Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
}

.my-list {
  height: 160px;
  background-color: rgb(179, 229, 252);
  padding-left: 1px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;    /* Enable scrollbar for the list */
}

.my-list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 8px 4px 8px 8px;
  border-width: thin;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
}
```

***Question:***
How can I make the dropdown menu appear directly below (*) the "..." button?

(*) Or appear directly above in the case of last item on the list.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a code example in a fiddle?

Comment: Hi Scarsam, here's the [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexMonkey/yswLnwhy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the effect that you're looking for?

```
<div class="my-list">
    <ul class= "nav">
        <li>
            <span>Item 1</span>
            <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu">
                <li><a>Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Set the overflow to overflow: visible;  needs to be "nav", and class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu"

Comment: Thank you TomBB.
Adding the class="nav" has achieved the desired behavior.

I would keep the CSS "overflow: auto" because I wanted the list to be of fixed height.  Changing overflow to visible seems to make the list height auto-grow when there are lots of items on the list.

Comment: Further credits to TomBB.  This is such an ingenious way of using the **nav** class with **dropdown-menu**.  I tried Googling the meaning of this **nav** class, yet most pages refer to either **nav-bar** or navigation in general.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.